# Boundary conditions in fluid dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions

I have been working on some questions and have noticed that my main problem is with finding boundary conditions for problems in fluid dynamics which involve oscillations. The two questions in particular are:

1. A sphere oscillating inside another sphere which is filled with fluid
2. A free surface between two separate fluids oscillating

How do I choose boundary conditions for such problems? I have thought about using a kinematic boundary condition but this doesn't seem to be enough to solve Laplace's equation.

---

Clarification:

1. The sphere executes small-amplitude oscillations about the centre of the larger sphere, which does not move (it is fixed in place).
2. The space is infinite, and there is a boundary between two different fluids, with different densities. Here the free surface between the two has small amplitude oscillations.

Comment: Which boundaries are you concerned about? All of them? Or just the ones on the surface?

Comment: @tpg2114 I think all of them. I don't know how many are needed to solve the equation, but I'd assume that all are needed

Comment: Okay, and for at least the first case, is the motion forced (ie. the inner sphere is being moved independent of the fluid motion) or is it responding to the fluid motion (ie. you shake up the outer sphere and then stop it suddenly and the inner one moves accordingly)?

Comment: @tpg2114 I have edited the question to clarify this

Comment: Well, the usual boundary condition is no-slip,which means that the velocity vanishes on the boundary. This has nothing to do with the specific problem you are solving. Obviously, a large amount of ink has been spilled regarding the question whether no-slip is physically correct in all cases, but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boundary conditions are generally obtained by setting the velocity at the boundary equal to the velocity of the surface (called the no slip condition). In the case of the spheres, suppose the radius of the small sphere is $r$, the large sphere is $R$, the oscillations described by  $a sin(\omega t)$ along the $x$ direction, then, assuming the center of the large sphere to be the origin, the boundary conditions will be :
$$\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial t }=a\omega cos(\omega t),\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial t }=0,\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial t }=0 \hspace{2cm}at \hspace{0.5cm} (x-asin(\omega t))^2+y^2+z^2-r^2=0$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial t }=0,\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial t }=0,\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial t }=0 \hspace{2cm}at \hspace{0.5cm} x^2+y^2+z^2-R^2=0$$
where the symbols have their usual meanings. although the second condition is a familiar Dirichlet type boundary condition, the first condition is a bit more rare and may be more difficult to apply when talking about numerical simulations, since much less is studied about it.

In the case of the free surface, the conditions at the surface will have a similar form though the exact equation will depend on the details.

Comment: You'll still need a boundary condition on pressure as well.

Comment: Yep that's true. But as pressure boundary conditions in such cases go, one can give it virtually any pressure distribution at $t=0 $and  it will evolve in time accordingly. this is done in many type fluid problems, a common example being the "Lid driven Cavity Flow" while using the SIMPLE Algorithm .

Comment: One can give it any initial condition (although poor choices will lead to poor convergence rates), but you still need to apply a condition on the wall. Usually it is $\partial p/\partial x_n = 0$ on walls and $p = p_\infty$ in the far-field. But you should mention it in your answer.